# Input Field Resize, Text Creeps after certain length

Tags: jquery, css, input

I'm creating an input field that behaves like a command prompt. As a visual cue to find the input field, I have brackets on the sides of the input box. When the user types, the input field resizes whenever they type a new character.

The only issue is that when typing too much, the left-side of the input field creeps outside the bounds of the field.

Here's the code for the input field:

```
<div class="line" id="command-wrapper">
    <span class="text-green">[</span><input id="command" autofocus contenteditable="true" size=1/><span class="text-green">]</span>
    <button id="submit"></button>
</div>
```

Here's the code that recalculates the size of the input field:

```
$('#command').keypress(function(e){
  if(e.which == 13){
    $('#submit').click();
  }
  $('#command').attr({'size': $('#command').val().length + 1});
});
```

Here's my JSfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mediocreb/8anw08k1/6/

In that example, if you type more than 17 characters, you'll see the effect. In my tests, it's even worse on mobile, usually "creeping" in just a few characters.

Answer (score 0):

I have Seen your code. it is not going outside the bounds of the Input Field. You have to Replace INPUT with textarea

```
<div class="line" id="command-wrapper">
<span class="text-green">[</span><textarea id="command" autofocus size=1> 
</textarea><span class="text-green">]</span>
<button id="submit"></button>
</div>
```

No change needed in Jquery

Add Css like this

```
textarea
{
 overflow:hidden;
 width:80%;
 border:none;
}
```

Comment: That is not how `textarea` works. While I had considered using a `textarea`, that would require a pretty sufficient overhaul of my code, especially since I would have to account for "height" and "width" values in the jQuery.

Thank you, though!